# Cart in Laravel with dynamicaly calculated price

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a webshop up and running, but not totally the way I want it to be.
Right now, my database contains the following:

- ID
- Title
- Description
- Price

But I don't want the price to come out of my database, as I calculate the price in a .js file to be able to change the format, material and way of laser-teching our product.
I have tried to change the way the price is fetched before it goes into my cart (which is based on a SESSION).

The price is calculated in a .js file, and then outputted to a div as well as a field that is constructed the following:

```
<input type='hidden' name='price' id='price' />
```

Since there is a lot of code involved, I have uploaded my project to GitHub. The link is:

[laravel webshop Dynamic price](https://github.com/gidimotje/laravel-webshop/tree/Dynamic-price)

My question is: What can I do to make the price in my cart the same as the dynamicaly calculated price at the product page?

Comment: When you calculate the price update the value of the hidden price div.   Then when you save pass the form parameters to you Controller and that should set the new price.   Also be aware that you need some way to validate the price on the server as the client can manipulate anything computed in JS or anything that exists on a HTML form with the element inspector.

Comment: I edited my jQuery to the following:
`document.getElementById('price').html = "&euro;"+total;` With total being the calculated price